# Latest files for localization of jquery Datepicker

Tags: localization, jquery-ui-datepicker

From where should we get the latest files for localization for jquery datepicker?
I found one link 
http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.11.1/i18n/jquery-ui-i18n.min.js

Or do i need to download one by one for each language from

https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n

Answer (score 0):

Where I work we use the files from this [github](https://github.com/jquery/jquery-ui/tree/master/ui/i18n) page

In fact, we used the complete `jquery-ui` folder from that repository.

If you take a look at [this example](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#localization) from the jquery-ui manual you can see they used the same files as from the github page.

```
...
<script src="datepicker-ar.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker-fr.js"></script>
<script src="datepicker-he.js"></script>
...
```